# How can I get whether an unix-like OS implement POSIX Semaphore?

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

How can I determine whether an unix-like OS(e.g. Mac OS X/Linux 2.6) implement POSIX Semaphore? Can I use sysconf to get it?

```
#include <unistd.h>
long sysconf(int name);
```

I just want to use POSIX semaphore api(sem_init/sem_wait/sem_post) in Linux/Mac OS X. I see both of Linux 2.6 and MAC OS X 10.6.6 implements POSIX semaphore. But how can I determine wheter an unix-like OS implement POSIX semaphore, while I write cross-platform applications.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `sysconf` is a runtime test. Presumably you'd want that check at compile time, no?

Comment: @Mat Sorry, I modified the description, hope I expressed clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sysconf is supposed to answer a query with the tag

```
 _POSIX_SEMAPHORES
```

with the supported version number. On POSIX systems you also have `getconf`. E.g on my linux box I get

```
>% getconf  _POSIX_SEMAPHORES
200809
```

So you could integrate this in a build script or something like that.
On linux you also should have a man page `posixoptions`.

But be careful to always check the return of `sem_init`. AFAIR, OS X implements this trivially as always returning `-1`.

Comment: Thank you. On my Mac OS X 10.6.6, _POSIX_SEMAPHORES is `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

You will have to ask your build system to check for it. I'd probably just look for `sem_init` and if it is there, just assume that it is a POSIX-like sem_init. In case of the autoconf system, that would look like

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([sem_init], [rt], ...)
```

Of course you can always do more elaborate testing with entire programs running a posting/waiting testing cycle.

Comment: I think that just asking for `sem_init` is not enough because there is at least one system (OS X ?) that implements it by just always returning `-1` :((